# What should i give input in this c program to come out of it?

Tags: c

I am a complete newbie programmer.i was reading  *the C progamming language* by  dennis ritchie  and brian kernighan and came across this program

[image]

I sucessully executed it,however whatever input i put i am unable to come out of the loop
can anyone explain why is this happening?
[image]

Comment: You may want to read this: [Why not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12149471)

Comment: You don't type the letters "EOF". You have to enter the EOF character as stated. For Windows that is `Ctrl-Z`, for Linux `Ctrl-D`. For Windows that must be preceded by, and followed by, a newline (the Enter key).

Comment: Generate a manual `EOF` which is `Ctrl + d` on Linux or `Ctrl + z` on windows (may need to tap twice on windows) Your loop is controlled by `while (c != EOF) { .. }`

Comment: Be aware that the book, however important, is outdated. `main()` is no longer valid in C, you want `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 1):

The loop condition is

```
while ( c != EOF )
```

so the loop will continue running until `getchar` returns `EOF`. This will happen when `getchar` encounters end-of-file or a stream error.

Since standard input appears to be linked to your keyboard, you will have to enter end-of-file on your keyboard to end the program.

On Linux, you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to enter end-of-file. On Microsoft Windows, you can accomplish the same with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. It may be necessary for this to be entered by itself on a single line, so that it is immediately preceded by a newline character and also immediately followed by a newline character.